# Designing a dropdown menu with 2 options in SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, xml, model-view-controller, sapui5

Designing a dropdown menu with 2 options and upon selecting any one of the options we get different popups with different set of input fields in them. I want to design the same in SAP UI5

I tried creating dropdown menu but could not get the popups upon selection of one menu from dropdown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        
        <title>Just a Menu</title>
        
        <script src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js''
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" 
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon"></script>
        <script>
var oMenuButton = new sap.m.MenuButton({
    text: "Menu",
    menu: [new sap.m.Menu({
        items: [
            new sap.m.MenuItem({
                text: "0",
                press: function () {
                    var oQuickView = new sap.m.ResponsivePopover({
                        content: [new sap.m.Input({value: "Hi!"})]
                    });
                    oQuickView.openBy(oMenuButton);
                }
            }),
            new sap.m.MenuItem({
                text: "1",
                press: function () {
                    var oQuickView = new sap.m.ResponsivePopover({
                        content: [new sap.m.Input({value: "Hello"}), new sap.m.Input({value: "World!"})]
                    });
                    oQuickView.openBy(oMenuButton);
                }
            })
        ]
    })]
});

oMenuButton.placeAt('content');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="content" class="sapUiBody">
    </body>
</html>
```